# how to combine two strings in TCL?

Tags: string, tcl

I have the following code in tcl:

```
set string1 "do the firstthing"
set string2 "do the secondthing"
```

how to make a combine two strings to have `"do the firstthing do the secondthing"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`append`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1031) like this:

```
% set string1 "do the firstthing"
% set string2 "do the secondthing"
% append string1 " " $string2
% puts $string1
do the firstthing do the secondthing
```

You can put them next to the other...

```
% set string1 "do the firstthing"
% set string2 "do the secondthing"
% puts "$string1 $string2"
do the firstthing do the secondthing
```

Or if your strings are in a list, you can use [`join`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1478) and specify the connector...

```
% set listofstrings [list "do the firstthing" "do the secondthing"]
% puts [join $listofthings " "]
do the firstthing do the secondthing
```

Answer (score 6):

String concatenation in tcl is just juxtaposition

```
set result "$string1$string2"
set result $string1$string
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the append command:

```
set string1 "do the firstthing"
set string2 "do the secondthing"
append var $string1 "," $string2
puts $var
# Prints do the firstthing,do the secondthing
```

Comment: The `append` command has a different semantics: you pass a *variable name* as first argument, and a variable list of *values* as other arguments. I edited your answer changing that: you must use `$string1` and `$string2` to access the values of the two variables and put the variable name you want to write to.

Comment: @MarcoPallante Posting a comment to point out any errors is fine, but it's up to Terry if he wants to edit his answer or not.

Comment: Thank you for your note, @Stijn, I'll do better the next time :)

Comment: Thanks @MarcoPallante! It should be correct now. Feel free to let me know if if a change needs to be made! Again, thanks for the update.